# Semantics markup for home sliders

Tags: html5

Is there a "best" or more suitable markup to home sliders?

I have the following markup. Since my sliders are related to articles, I decided to put `article` as the main `container`.

Note: I am using Owl Slider to convert what is inside `.home-slider` actually in a slider.

```
<section class="home-slider">
    <!-- Slide One -->
    <article>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Little Description</h2>
        <a href="">Call to Action Link</a>
    </article>

    <!-- slide Two -->
    <article>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Little Description</h2>
        <a href="">Call to Action Link</a>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: What makes your "*sliders*" slide?  I think that we may need a little more context to be able to give you a proper review.

Comment: Hello, I use Owl Carousel like this: `home-slider owl-carousel` and all the ´<article>´ get converted to slides. owl carousel preserves the markup.

Answer (score 2):

For me the main semantic question is whether you should have a section containing articles or an article containing sections. Or perhaps even an article containing other sub-articles.

From the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element):

> The `article` element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

It really comes down to the content of your articles and sections.

- If each slide could be viewed as an independent thing, then marking them with `article` seems fine.
- If however, you'd expect the slides to be viewed in sequence as in slide show, I'd say the slides should be sections instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow the advice from the HTML spec, you [should use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349232/1591669) the heading element that represents the actual rank, not a `h1`. It doesn’t matter for user agents that support the outline algorithm, but it can matter for older user agents, especially for accessibility.

The description shouldn’t be in a heading element. Otherwise the following content (in your case: the link) would be in scope of this description, not in scope of the top heading. Use `p` instead.

For the link, you [could use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44013589/1591669) the `bookmark` link type, if it goes to the page that has the full content that this slide is a teaser for.

So a slide could use this markup (assuming that the slider appears on the level below the page’s `h1`):

```html
<article>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Little Description</p>
  <a href="" rel="bookmark">Call to Action Link</a>
</article>
```